# How does one extract numbers from a string in a dataframe and add the multiple of these numbers in a new column of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here's an example of how I managed to extract the numerical values  from dimensions and multiply them to return the volume:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dict
d = {'model': ['merc','ford'], 'dimensions': ['4.31 m x 2 m x 3.222 m', '2 m']}

# create data frame from dict
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# this extracts all instances of numbers but creates a new data frame with each num in new row
x = df['dimensions'].str.extractall(r'(\d*\.?\d+)')

# converts all numeric strings to float
x[0] = x[0].astype(float)

#multiplies the dimensions of the van
y = x.loc[0].prod(axis=0)
print(y)
```

Here's my attempted function to repeat the example from the code above but to return it to the new column in the data frame.

```
def my_function(col,row):
    out = 0
    if col.str.extractall(r'(\d*\.?\d+)') == True:
        out = col.str.extractall(r'(\d*\.?\d+)')
        col[0] = col[0].astype(float)
        z = col.loc[row].prod(axis=0)
    return z

# logic to create new column based on function and existing data.
df['volume'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(df['dimensions'], df.index)
```

Could somebody please help me in getting this volume data back into the original dataframe as a new column.

Comment: how do you calculate the volume of the second car? It only has one dimension (2m)

Comment: Added it in as sometimes the data type is complete. It was just to aid the reasoning of the regex part. Relevant to item as a whole but not to the specific problem which is now wonderfully answered by Scott Boston.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, do you want to try:

```
df['volume'] = df['dimensions'].str.extractall(r'(\d*\.?\d+)').astype(float).unstack().prod(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  model              dimensions    volume
0  merc  4.31 m x 2 m x 3.222 m  27.77364
1  ford                     2 m   2.00000
```